# Vue JS: how bind an checkbox with related select in simple Vue example?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an overview of users. In my example, an user can select a list of users and select a personal role.

But I really doesn't understand how I can make this example working in Vue JS. So I get an overview of the selected user ID's with their selecter role ID's.

Who can help and make this example working...?

```js
    var data = {
        users: { 
          { id: 1, name: 'John'}, 
          { id: 2, name: 'Donald'} 
        },
        roles: { 
          { id: 1, name: 'Administrator'}, 
          { id: 2, name: 'Editor'} 
        },
        form: {
          users: {
          }
        }
    }

    var demo = new Vue({
        el: '#demo',
        data: data
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
Add new users:

<div class="row" v-for="user in users">
    <div class="col s6">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.users[user.id]" v-bind:value="user.id"/>
            <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col s6">
        <select class="browser-default" v-model="form.users[user.id][role_id]">
            <option v-for="role in roles" v-bind:value="role.id">{{ role.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
<br/>
Selected users + role:

<div v-for="in f in form.users">
  User ID: {{ f.id }}
  Role id: {{ f.role_id }}
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Is the id in the user object is the user id? 2. Is the id in the role object is the role id? 3. Do you want a dropdown of users ? 4. Do you want checkboxes of roles to be selected as role for the selected user(user that got selected in the dropdown)?

Comment: @shivam Singh 1. yes 2. yes 3. no I will a result like this: "Selected users: { { user_id: 1, role_id: 2 }, { user_id:2, role_id: 1 } }

Comment: Is the role drop down a requirement to add to the end list result?

Comment: @Feel The Noise: the role dropdown for every user: if I have 10 users, I have 10 role dropdowns.

Comment: @angelique000 checkout my answer, maybe that helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that what you want is somewhat similar to what I did below:

```js
var data = {
    users: [
        { id: 1, name: 'John'},
        { id: 2, name: 'Donald'}
    ],
    roles: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Administrator'},
        { id: 2, name: 'Editor'}
    ],
    form: {
        users: []
    }
}

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: data,
    created: function () {
        this.form.users = this.users.map(el => {
            return {
                id: el.id,
                role: '',
                checked: false
            };
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
Add new users:

<div id="demo">
    <div class="row" v-for="(user, index) in users">
        <div class="col s6">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"
                 v-bind:value="user.id" v-model="form.users[index].checked">
                <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col s6" v-if="form.users[index].checked">
            <select class="browser-default" v-model="form.users[index].role">
                <option v-for="role in roles" v-bind:value="role.id">
                    {{ role.name }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>
    <br/>
    Selected users + role:

    <div v-for="f in form.users" v-if="f.checked">
        User ID: {{ f.id }} -> Role id: {{ f.role }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The data structure is very similar to yours (I only changed the `users` from object to array, and the same for `roles`).

The trick here is the `created` [Instance Lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) that prepares the `form.users` object to the data.

I also took advantage of [conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) to only show the roles dropdown if the user is selected, that way the DOM and design is cleaner.

It's also possible to only show the user in the list if a role is selected, it's as easy as changing from `<div v-for="f in form.users" v-if="f.checked">` to `<div v-for="f in form.users" v-if="f.checked && f.role !== ''">`

Try it out, I hope I was able to help you somehow!

Comment: Thanks very much! This is a really very good and clean solution!! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Happy coding with vue :D

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure in which context you are using this. But Vue is a data driven framework, if your intention is to do something with the users  which have been check and have a role, then you can direct your focus to the user. This is a very basic example but hope it get you started.

```js
var data = {
        
        users: [ 
          { id: 1, name: 'John', check: false, role:'' }, 
          { id: 2, name: 'Donald', check: false, role:''} 
        ],
        roles: [
          { id: 1, name: 'Administrator'}, 
          { id: 2, name: 'Editor'} 
        ],
    };

    var demo = new Vue({
        el: '#demo',
        data: data,
        computed: {
          checkUsers: function() {
            return this.users.filter(function(user) {
              return user.check === true;
            })
          }
        }
 
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
Add new users:

  <div id="demo">

    <div class="row" v-for="user in users">
      <div class="col s6">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox"    
                     v-model="user.check"/>
              <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
          </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col s6">
          <select class="browser-default"
                  v-model="user.role">
              <option v-for="role in roles"   :value="role.name" >{{ role.name }}</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <br/>
      
      Selected users + role:
    </div> 
          <div v-for="user in checkUsers">
            {{ user.name }}
            {{ user.role }}
        
      </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: @FeelTheNoise thanks :) I not an expert in Vue, but this seems as a good start.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It's a perfect solution. But 1 little question: is it possible without computed() method? In my application I have to post the selected users (incl. their roles) to the server. Is that possible without computed() method?

Comment: You can access the computed values from any function in your vue and send the data just like any other data in you component. I am going to give you a link to a tutorial on ajax calls with vue. The entire tutorial is great so it may help you with the rest of your project. https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/18